Understanding the data event in the context of javascript (node) stdout
My assumption is that the data event should only really be used in conjunction with stdin... (in the context of using stdin and stdout)
I do not understand why it can be used with stdout... (basically - why is it even permitted?)... When it is used - it seems to somehow overwrite any previous stdin.on("data"...) listener - and has even more odd behaviour when used before a stdin.on("data"...) listener
Example 1:
process.stdin.on("data", (data) => {
  process.stdout.write(data.toString());
});

process.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
   process.stdout.write(data.toString().toUpperCase());
});

When run from the terminal and inputting (one after the other) test0, test1, test2 and test 3 yields...:
test0
TEST0
test1
TEST1
test2
TEST2
test3
TEST3
It would therefore appear that the stdin listener is not operational(?)...
Example 2:
process.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  process.stdout.write(data.toString().toUpperCase());
});

process.stdin.on("data", (data) => {
  process.stdout.write(data.toString());
});

When run from the terminal and inputting (one after the other) test0, test1, test2 and test 3 yields...:
test0
test0
test1
TEST1
test2
test2
test3
TEST3
This the second example seems to flip between the two listeners...
Apologies if this is a really stupid question, I have looked high and low for the answer but have been unable to find an answer....
